# How to make a border-only text in CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to reproduce this kind of text, with transparency inside of it and only a border : [image: Example of what I'm trying to make]

Is this possible to make this in CSS, even with Javascript ?

Comment: Refer: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by :

```
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
```

Reference:  https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Answer (score 3):

Using [text-stroke](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/):

```css
span {
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```

```html
<span>ICY</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Technically, you can add a border with some browser-specific prefixes, but **don't. IF YOU DO THIS, IT WILL NOT BE SUPPORTED BY ALL BROWSERS.** Unfortunately, there is no way to produce an actual border with CSS currently, at least within a regular HTML element. However, you can achieve something similar with SVG.